# mySQL Append to LIst

Tags: mysql

I have a list being output from mySQL with a Count of 20 items.

Users will add and delete items that go into the list so the ID of the items is not consecutive.  They might be 5, 10, 12, 13, 14, 27, 28, 31, 38, 40.  The list is Limited to 20 items.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE fields = vars ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

User will continue to add and remove items while this list is displayed on the screen.  I have the value of the last id in the example here, this is 40.

Some of these items may be deleted, and new items will be added.

How can i re run this query starting from the last known id.  Do i add a WHERE ID > 40.  Can i put the WHERE clause after the LIMIT 0,10 clause.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE fields = vars ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10 WHERE id > $lastid
```

The main point here is i dont want to show already shown items, and i dont know if items have been deleted so doing a 1,10 may bring up incorrect results.  I need the next 10 results immediately after the last displayed item.

Comment: I think you should not worry about deleted items. It will be a real pain to control whether an item should be shown or not based on the modification of items. You should just stick with the order of the ids and fix a number of elements for each page. Then you just need to control these values with the `LIMIT` clause. Always start with `LIMIT 1, 10` with `10` being the number of elements of a page, next page will be 1+10, 10 which is `LIMIT 11,10`. All pagination work as this. Controlling what should be shown would involve adding unnecessary complexity to your system, like cookies, other tables

Comment: And an awful logic to check it to every user that are seeing the list and more, each step of each user going forward and backward in the pagination.

Comment: I did not add it as an answer because it is an opinion, even though knowing that it is the default behavior of almost all systems.

Comment: Im fully aware of pagination, i have it running on several search pages.  This is a list that is appended down the screen of items with a link to append at the bottom of the list, i would like to add a scroll trigger so that when a user hits the bottom of the page, it automatically starts the append.  I cant have items repeat themselves because previous items were deleted.

Comment: So, in saying that its not an awful logic, its a User Interface requirement to scroll down the screen, and not tab through pages back and next.

Comment: What you can do to diminish your work is do as I said, and check on the client side whether that elements are already shown on the list. And there is also the other side. Say a user A have a list with ids 1 to 10 being shown and a user B deletes the item 1, then the user A scrolls down the list to update it, it will shown only new items but the item 1 will still be present which is wrong right?

Comment: That's a matter of weighing the possibilities. awful logic to implement it. I agree that it would be good to the user. You have to ask if a user would care about seeing an item twice knowing that someone can delete another item.

Comment: No its not wrong.  And yes, a user will care.  How is it awful logic.  I have a last used ID for each users screen. they are going to call the sql server anyway to bring up the next ten results.  Their screen will not change, the next ten results should reflect that. It would be a simple SQL query using a where id > lastid.  Its called User Interface, not some half assed heres a repeat of 3 items because they got deleted while you were browsing.  Maybe its 7 items, then its not a list in order for that user now is it.  What if 1000 items are added and 300 removed after the users viewing.

Comment: I came here for answers, not some misguided opinion

Answer (score 0):

Save the `id` value that was last retrieved, and add a condition in the existing  WHERE clause. (You can't add a second WHERE clause following LIMIT, that's not valid. The SELECT statement gets a single WHERE clause.)

I'm a little confused, because the query in the question shows ordering by id in DESCENDING order. In that case, you would want the next id value that is *less than* the last retrieved value.

If you are ordering in ascending value, then ...

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM table t
 WHERE t.fields = vars
   AND t.id > ? 
 ORDER BY t.id ASC 
 LIMIT 10
```

The question mark there is a bind placeholder... assuming that you are using prepared statements. If you aren't using prepared statements, then use a literal in place of the bind placeholder... the value you last retrieved.

If you are ordering by id in descending order, then you would want to retrieve rows that have id value *less than* the last one you previously retrieved.

It is not at all difficult to preserve the id value of the last row retrieved, put that into a hidden input on the web page, and read that back in when the form is posted. (Ignore the misinformed suggestions from Jorge Campos.)

Comment: Thankyou.  You have just made me aware of something that i hadnt thought of.  I had them in descending order as the last was placed at the top of the screen.  I will have to append to the top of the list and have old results pushed down the screen.  Or i will have to change the order.  It would be preferable to keep the new entries in view.  Something to discuss with others.  I also notice you took the 0,10 out and left it at just 10, no need to paginate on a known return of 10.  In my case it is 50 or 100.

Comment: I do have one last question.  Given there is only one where clause, can it go after the LIMIT 10.  `select * from table order by id desc limit 10 where id > lastid` is that a valid statement, or does it need to precede the order and limit.

Comment: The WHERE clause cannot be after the ORDER BY clause, or after the LIMIT clause.  In that example, the WHERE clause would need to be after the table list and before the ORDER BY. There's only one place that can go in your statement.  MySQL syntax is very specific about the order of the clauses in a SELECT statement.

Comment: `LIMIT 10` is the same as `LIMIT 0,10`. (skip the first zero rows, and return (up to) the next ten rows.

Comment: Thankyou very much, i now have a handle on what i need to look into.  And some javascript to look at to append the ajax call to the container.  I appreciate the confirmations, i was heading in the right direction.  Just had things a little bit about face.

Comment: Just to be clear here. `It is not at all difficult to preserve the id value of the last row retrieved` I was not saying that THIS is awful to do, I was concerned about storing a list of viewed itens to a specific user session. You have to store the list of that specific user saw in order to keep only new itens to appear. You misunderstood me. Handling the pagination is fairly easy. Control what the user saw in his specific browsing session is the awful logic to handle. You have also to control all the actions done by the user on that list and how to handle multiples changes from another users.

Comment: Apparently the OPs also misunderstood me and even think that I was being rude, which is not the case at all. At least that is the way his comments seems. I was just showing a bigger scenario that I think he doesn't saw (but it is just a guess, based on his comments)